# Finding $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} (X_{n} = 2 \mid X_{0} =1 ) $ and $\mathbb{E} [ s^{T} \mid X_{0} =1 ]$ for a Markov chain.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I am working on Markov chains and I have problems with the following exercise. I think I have successfully solve the first two subproblems but I do not know how to solve the latter two. I include the work done, because I expect it to be informative for the last two subproblems (and maybe parts need to be used in there).

We are given the following Markov chain with state space $I= \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ and one-step transition matrix

$ P=
\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 1/5 & 1/10 & 0 &1/10 & 1/10 \\ 
0 & 7/10 & 0 & 0 & 3/10 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1/10 & 0 & 9/10 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1/10 & 0 & 1/5 & 7/10 & 0\\ 
3/10 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7/10
\end{pmatrix}
$

Now mind you, $p_{ij}$ represents the probability of going from state $i$ to state $j$.

**a)** Calculate the expected numbers of jumps to hit state 4 starting from state 2

**b)** Find all invariant distributions

**c)** Compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} (X_{n} = 2 \mid X_{0} =1 ) $

**d)** Let $T$ be the time when $X_{n}$ leaves states $1$ for the last time (i.e., never to return again). $T$ is undefined if state $1$ is never visited. Compute $\mathbb{E} [ s^{T} \mid X_{0} =1 ]$, for $s \in [0,1]$.

Now my work so far:

**a)** I define $k_{i}$ as the number of steps needed to go from state $i$ to state $4$. Then, when we start from state $2$ we find the following set of equations:

$
\begin{align}
k_{2} &= 1 + \frac{7}{10} k_{2} + \frac{3}{10}k_{5}\\
k_{5} &= 1 + \frac{7}{10} k_{5} + \frac{1}{10} k_{2} + \frac{1}{5}k_{4}
\end{align}
$
and since $k_{4} = 0$ we can solve this and find $k_{2} = 10.$

**b)** I see we have two closed classes, namely $\{3\}$ and $\{2,4,5\}$. Obviously one invariant distribution is $(0,0,1,0,0,0)$, since this would keep us in state $3$. But to find the other one I made a new matrix, consisting of states $2,4,5$ from $P$ and hence defined:

$P^{*} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
7/10 & 0 & 3/10\\ 
1/10 & 9/10 & 0\\ 
1/10 & 1/5 & 7/10
\end{pmatrix},
$
since we are working with left-hand eigenvectors (or a steady state probability row vector), I find the eigenvector that corresponds with eigenvalue $1$ (which we know exists, since $P^{*}$ is irreducible) of the transpose of $P^{*}$, and I then find $(1,2,1)$ which gives me a distribution of $(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4})$. Hence I conclude all invariant distributions are given by
$$ \pi = \alpha (0,0,1,0,0,0) + (1-\alpha) \left(0,\frac{1}{4}, 0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4},0 \right)$$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$

**c)** Now I do not know how to tackle this. I expect that I have to use the Markov property and hence condition on $X_{n-1}$ but I do not see how.

**d)** I expect to use a probability generating function, but I do not see how I can incorporate the idea of a stopping time with this...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The basic idea in c is that $P(X_n=2)=P(X_n=2 \mid X_n \in \{ 2,4,5 \}) P(X_n \in \{ 2,4,5 \})$. This is true in general, obviously, but it is useful in the limit because we can compute the first factor in the limit by finding the invariant distribution on that class. Then you need the second part, which in the limit is the probability to hit that class before hitting any other closed class (because in the limit you won't be in any transient class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c)

Convergence to equilibrium theorem about Markov chains states that if a Markov chain has an irreducible and aperiodic transition matrix $P$ and $P$ has an invariant distribution $\pi$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n=j)=\pi_j$$ We want to apply this statement to answer point c). Note that the submatrix $P^*$ is aperiodic and irreducible and has the invariant distribution $\pi=(1/4,2/4,1/4)$ (it's a bit different from the one you found). Let's $T$ denote the time when the chain enters the closed class $\{2,4,5\}$. Using the above statement we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n=2\vert T<\infty)=\pi_2=1/4$$ On the other hand, it is clear that $$\mathbb{P}(X_n=2\vert T=\infty)=0$$ Hence, we have $$\mathbb{P}(X_n=2\vert X_0=1)=\mathbb{P}(T<\infty\vert X_0=1)\mathbb{P}(X_n=2\vert T<\infty)+\mathbb{P}(T=\infty\vert X_0=1)\mathbb{P}(X_n=2\vert T=\infty)=\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{P}(T<\infty\vert X_0=1)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}$$

d)

Note that $T$ is also the time when $X_n$ enters $A=\{2,3,4,5\}$ which is almost surely finite. Take $i\notin A$, then note that $$\mathbb{E}_i[s^T\vert X_1=j]=\begin{cases}s&\text{$j\in A$} \\ s\mathbb{E}_j[s^T]&\text{$j\notin A$}\end{cases}$$
Put $k_i:=\mathbb{E}_i[s^T]$ for $i\notin A$.
We have$$k_i=\sum_{j\in I}\mathbb{P}_i(X_1=j)\,\mathbb{E}_i[s^T\vert X_1=j]=s\sum_{j\in A}p_{i,j}+s\sum_{j\notin A}p_{i,j}k_j$$ We have the system$$\begin{cases}k_1=s\frac{4}{10}+s(\frac{5}{10}k_1+\frac{1}{10}k_6)\\ k_6=s(\frac{3}{10}k_1+\frac{7}{10}k_6)\end{cases}$$The solution is $$k_1\equiv\mathbb{E}_1[s^T]=\frac{s(10-7s)}{8(5-2s)(5-4s)}$$

Comment: Your $\pi$ above doesn't add up to 1. It looks like the correct invariant distribution on that class is $(\pi_2,\pi_4,\pi_5)=(1/4,1/2,1/4)$.

Comment: you are right. I've edited the answer

Comment: Also I don't see how you got $P(T<\infty \mid X_0=1)$ to be $1/3$. It seems to me that it is $(1/5+1/10)/(1/5+1/10+1/10)=3/4$.

Comment: Finally I think it is relevant that this problem is special in that one cannot go directly from 6 to a closed class. This affects how you do both c and d (because otherwise you need to resolve the probability distribution of which state you enter a closed class from).

Comment: yes, it is 3/4. Thank you Ian

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to c) I found the following:

let $h_{i}$ be the hitting probability of state $i$ to state $\{2,4,5\}$. Then surely

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 2 \mid X_{0} =1 ) = h_{1} \frac{1}{4},$$
where $\frac{1}{4}$ comes from part (b) (the probability of being in state $2$ once you are established in the closed class $\{2,4,5\})$. Now note $h_{2}=h_{4}=h_{5} = 1$ and $h_{3} = 0$.

Then we find
$$
\begin{align}
h_{1} &= \frac{1}{2} h_{1} + \frac{1}{5} h_{2} + \frac{1}{10}h_{3} +\frac{1}{10}h_{6} +\frac{1}{10}h_{5}\\
h_{1} &= \frac{1}{2}h_{1} + \frac{1}{10}h_{6} + \frac{3}{10}\\
h_{6} &= \frac{7}{10}h_{6} + \frac{3}{10}h_{1} = h_{1},
\end{align}
$$
which together gives
$h_{1} = \frac{3}{4}$
and thus

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 2 \mid X_{0} =1 ) = \frac{3}{4} \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{16}.$$